# Dead Space missing log entries in new game plus

Tags: dead-space

I just started a new game+ in original Dead Space to read/listen to all the log entries I might have missed on my first run through the game, but some log entries remain locked. To be more precise, I have exactly one locked entry in each of chapters 1, 2, 4 and 7.

For example, I have a missing (empty) log entry between "Replacing the tram" and "Maintenance bay unlocked" in chapter 1.

I was pretty thorough when I was playing, and had actually found most of the log entries while playing the first time (I even found the Peng statuette without even knowing it existed in the first place), so I'm not even sure if anything was unlocked in new game plus that I didn't find myself already.

I thought all log entries were supposed to be unlocked in new game plus. Are these some kind of special logs that can only be found and unlocked only in new game plus? Or is this some kind of glitch?

I'm playing PC version of the game, in case that matters.

**UPDATE**

Checking on the list of all logs provided by TheFaster I found that some "story" logs are actually missable - there are at least two mutually exclusive logs, so you'll have to complete the game at least twice to unlock them all, and some logs are only unlocked when you do certain things in "wrong" order and are basically reminders that "you must do X before you can proceed doing Y". The mutually exclusive logs are such reminder logs too, so it's not really worth beating the game again just to unlock one of those.

There was also one hidden text log that I missed, which also was the only missing log that actually contributed to the story.

I don't know why these logs aren't unlocked after completing the game, but I guess it's not such a big deal after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I feel like your best bet would be to compare the logs you have to a [list of logs.](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_logs_in_Dead_Space) That way, you'll know exactly what logs you're missing. If you have all the logs in the list, it's a glitch.